# Git push into second account

Tags: git, macos, github

I'm in a situation where I have two GitHub accounts (one is my primary one and the other is basically used to share information between two different computers). 
I am trying to push my work onto my secondary account and created a new origin2 to push into that account through terminal but it is not going through. Any and all advice would be appreciated. The repo names are repos in the actual accounts.

```
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:sekkinsan/bloc-jams.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:sekkinsan/bloc-jams.git (push)
origin2 git@github.com:jjydevt/dummy.git (fetch)
origin2 git@github.com:jjydevt/dummy.git (push)
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$ git push origin2 master
To github.com:jjydevt/dummy.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jjydevt/dummy.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:bloc-jams JYUN$


Config SSH
# default GitHub
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa

Host github.com/jjydevt
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jjydevt
```

Comment: The message is pretty self explanatory. Your origin2 remote's master branch has commits in it that you don't have in your local version of the master branch. if you've rebased or something then you'll need to force push (`-f` or `--force`)

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want to overwrite the existing repository in origin2.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! Since I will be replacing the information in my origin2 I will just be forcing both.